# MO not created in partial stock in MTS

Tags: unit-testing, odoo-8

In MTS Order,Available customer orders for 1000 units any my available stock 900 unit and this cases I have created Manufacturing  Order (MO) is created but I does not reflecting the stock.

please help me to short it out this issue.